# How to keep the FormKey updated on pages with Varnish enabled?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, varnish, form-key

I'm running a Magento 2.3.4 store behind a Varnish server.
I can't keep the FormKey up to date in the frontend as the pages are served by the Varnish caches, so I have errors in sending the newsletter and the message from the contact form.

How can I keep the FormKey updated on frontend pages?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to generate the *FormKey* in Varnish and parse it into the HTML.

That way Varnish can cache a page, cache the FormKey that was generated by Magento, but overwrite it with a key that was generated by Varnish.

I'm assuming it will look like this:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="xxx" />
```

### The plan

The plan would be to render the value of the *FormKey* using *Eddge Side Includes*. The *ESI tag* would be processed by Varnish and replaced with a *FormKey* generated by Varnish.

This is what it would look like in terms of HTML sent by Magento:

```
<esi:include src="/formkey"/>
```

Varnish can process *ESI* and would intercept that `/formkey` URL and synthetically return the right HTML including a new *FormKey*. The output would be:

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="xxx" />
```

Where `xxx` would be replaced with an actual *FormKey*.

### Need some input from you

I have a couple of questions regarding the *FormKey*:

- What's the format of such a key? How is it generated?
- Is a *FormKey* stateful? Does it depend on any cookie value of PHP session?

### Varnish requirements

Generating such a *FormKey* is not done using standard *VCL*. It will probably require installing one or more [Varnish modules (*VMODs*)](http://varnish-cache.org/vmods/).

If you're running your setup on AWS, Azure, or GCP, there are easy effective ways of leveraging some of Varnish Software's enterprise modules. These wouldn't require using ESI, and are directly capable of replacing values in your reponse body.

If you're not in the Cloud, you can't benefit from these enterprise modules without paying a license fee upfront, unfortunately.

### Next steps

Please send me some information on the *FormKey* constraints and possible state dependencies.

If you're on AWS, Azure, or GCP, please also let me know.

Comment: thanks! i will try this solution first with varnish open source modules

Comment: Actually i'm running Varnish and Magento on private server